# Message=Incorrect syntax near ')'. Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to load csv into my database but I keep getting the following exception

> Message=Incorrect syntax near ')'

My code block is as shown below.

```cs
var lineNumber = 0;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-3EHXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXX_XXXX_Monitoring;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\XXX\\XXX DATA\\xxxxx_xxxx_2011.csv"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if(lineNumber !=0)
            {
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine("Before DB Insertion");
                var sql = "INSERT INTO XXXXXXX_Monitoring.dbo.LimsDataLists VALUES ('" + values[0] + "','" + values[1] + "','" + values[2] + "','" + "','" + values[3] + "','" + values[4] + "','" + values[5] + "','" + values[6] + "','" + values[7] + "','" + values[8] + "','" +
                    values[9] + "','" + values[10] + "','" + values[11] + "','" + values[12] + "','" + values[13] + "','" + values[14] + "','" +
                    values[15] + "','" + values[16] + "','" + values[17] + "','" + values[18] + "','" + values[19] + "','" + values[20] + "','" +
                    values[21] + "','" + values[22] + "','" + values[23] + "','" + values[24] + "','" + values[25] + "','" + values[26] + "','" +
                    values[27] + "','" + values[28] + "','" + values[29] + "','" + values[30] + "','" + values[31] + "','" + values[32] + "','" +
                    values[33] + "','" + values[34] + "','" + values[35] + "','" + values[36] + "','" + values[37] + "'," + values[38] + ")";

                var cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine("Data import Complete!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What's the value of `sql` when this is erroring?

Comment: Side note: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You should use parametrized queries instead

Comment: Could you clarify what this has to do with Entity Framework? I don't see anything EF-related in this question.

Comment: If you use SqlParameters instead of concatenating strings you will greatly reduce the opportunity for syntax errors.

Comment: You are missing single quotes around `value[38]`. It should be `,'" + values[38] + "')");`

Comment: @Crowcoder I wish I could upvote you another 100 **If you use SqlParameters instead of concatenating strings you will greatly reduce the opportunity for syntax errors** Injection is not just about security, it is also, and more so, about correctness

Comment: @SomeBody Wrong order, do parameterization first

Comment: The only proper way of doing such queries, is not using string concatenation but parameterized queries. This will, in 99% of the cases get rid of "strange" syntax errors as the current one, where you are missing the quotes around your last value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use EF you can use `SqlParameter` instead plain query text:

```
var sqlParams = new List<object>();
var valuesList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter($"@Value{i}", values[i]));
    valuesList.Add($"@Value{i}");
}

var sql = $"INSERT INTO EMR_LIMS_Monitoring.dbo.LimsDataLists VALUES ({ string.Join(", ", valuesList)})";
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
```

Comment: You should always specify the type of an SQL Parameter. Because the way you suggest it, its basically the same problem as discussed here https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/  or  here https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that error lies in the *sql* variable. So, you need to debug your code to catch the string value that the *sql* variable has. And then run the sql string value somewhere in *SQL IDE*. Hope that this way you will find where he got stuck into; it's probably a syntax error in your *INSERT INTO* query.